# Rails omniauth-twitter dynamic client id and secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, clientid, omniauth-twitter

for omniuath-twiiter i want to set multiple developers accounts But i am not able set enviroment variable at run time

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

you can add the id and secret into config file like `config.yml` and ignore the `config.yml` in `.gitignore` , track a `config.example.yml` file to make every developers easy to use.

```
omniauth:
   providers:
       - { name: 'google_oauth2', app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
           app_secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
           args: { access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: '' } }
       - { name: 'twitter', app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
           app_secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'}
```

and config `omniuath-twiiter` just use params in config.yml via `Settingslogic` gem , it is easy to use, put the code into a file in `config/initializers/`

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml
  namespace Rails.env
end

module Foobar
  def self.config
    Settings
  end
end
```

then config the omniauth like below:

```
Foobar.config.omniauth.providers.each do |provider|
   config.omniauth provider['name'].to_sym, provider['app_id'], provider['app_secret'], provider['args']
end
```

that's it

Comment: Thanks for the reply . but i need to call app_id and app_secret from database.actually i need multiple twiiter  developers accounts for same application